# Бэкграунд через CSS

Tags: css

Доброго всем.
Решил сделать подложку сайту и вот что-то не пойму:
(сайт на локалке, без сервера, т.е. просто html)
Вот этот код, например, корректно срабатывает в браузере, т.е. отображается картинка:

```
background-image:url(http://siteaddress.ru/logo.gif);
```

А этот, когда файл на компе, нет.

```
background-image:url(images/logo.gif);
```

А сам DreamWeaver в дизайнерской части картинку показывает.
Почему так происходит?

Comment: для начала попробуйте указать путь абсолютно (т.е. `/images/logo.gif`)

Comment: тег base запрятался оказывается в header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот сам-то тупанул!!!
тег base в header от старого шаблона не убрал!
Всё заработало! Всё заотображалось!
Отсюда понятно почему абсолютные работали, а относительные нет.